# LessCss rgba and @vars

Tags: css, syntax-error, less

I'm trying to make a function with [LessCss](http://lesscss.org) but i get an error:

```
.transparent-border (@alpha:.15, @color:'0,0,0', @type: solid, @size:1px) {
    @val: @size @type rgba(@color, @alpha);
    border: @val;
}
```

The error
error evaluating function `rgba`
@val: @size @type `rgba(@color, @alpha)`;

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code instead:

```
.transparent-border (@alpha:.15, @r:0, @g:0, @b:0, @type: solid, @size:1px) {
    @val: @size @type rgba(@r, @g, @b, @alpha);
    border: @val;
}
```

It doesn't only work, but it also makes more sense. In your previous attempt, you would have to pass the color in a string:

```
#myElement{
    /*Old, not-working implementation*/
    .transparent-border (0.15, "0, 0, 0", solid, 1px);

    /*New, neat and working method */
    .transparent-border (0.15, 0, 0, 0, solid, 1px);

    /*Since these are the default settings, it's equivalent to*/
    .transparent-border
}
```

Parsed LESS:

```
#myElement {
     border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0, 0.15);
}
```